# How to apply the same style to all atribute tags?

Tags: html, css, vue.js, tailwind-css

I have this in a `vue.js` file:

```
 <a
          href="#"
          class="my-3 block text-gray-300 hover:text-gray-100 text-sm font-medium duration-700"
        >
          Installation
        </a>
        <a
          href="#"
          class="my-3 block text-gray-300 hover:text-gray-100 text-sm font-medium duration-700"
        >
          Release Notes
        </a>
        <a
          href="#"
          class="my-3 block text-gray-300 hover:text-gray-100 text-sm font-medium duration-700"
        >
          Upgrade Guide
        </a>
```

And I want to remove the classes or at least shorten  them:

```
 <a
          href="#"
        >
          Installation
        </a>
        <a
          href="#"
        >
          Release Notes
        </a>
```

I tried placing them between `<div` but nothing is displayed.

Comment: Could you just make a class like .my-great-link with the styles you want, and use that? Otherwise, if the framework adds their own classes, you could inspect the HTML and find the classes the framework is applying to those anchors and apply your extra styles directly to their class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see that you have "html" and "css" listed in your tags.  I have not used vue before, although I do know Javascript.

I would advise you to create a CSS file with a custom class and reference the custom class in your html page.  Here is an example web page:

HTML file:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="Content/Site.css" type="text/css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="#" class="my-custom-class">Installation</a>
        <a href="#" class="my-custom-class">Release Notes</a>
        <a href="#" class="my-custom-class">Upgrade Guide</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the associated CSS file that is referenced (NOTE: the CSS file is located within a "Content" folder inside the root directory):

```
/*Site.css*/

.my-custom-class {
    color: gray;
    font-weight: bold;

}

.my-custom-class:hover {
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

I hope that this helps!  Please let me know if you have any other questions or concerns.

***EDIT***

Per request, I'm making an optional CSS file to select the elements we want to affect without specifying a class in the html.

CSS:

/*Site.css*/

```
body > a {
    color: gray;
    font-weight: bold;

}

body > a:hover {
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

If you use this method of element selection then you can safely remove the class attribute from each of the  elements inside of the HTML file.

Please let me know if you have any other questions or concerns.

Answer (score 1):

You can extract a set of classes in Tailwind using `@apply` in your main (un-compiled) CSS file.
See here for more details and examples: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/extracting-components#extracting-component-classes-with-apply

For your example you could do something like this in your CSS file:

```
.link {
    @apply my-3 block text-gray-300 hover:text-gray-100 text-sm font-medium duration-700;
}
```

And update your HTML to something like this to make use of the extracted class:

```
<a href="#" class="link">
    Installation
</a>
<a href="#" class="link">
    Release Notes
</a>
```